# Nav menu shifting right when bootstrap modal popup displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

When modal pops up the right scroll dissapeared the main contend not moving -  so that is fine, but nav menu shifting right filling the scroll space.
Then when I am closing the popup scroll appeares and menu shifted back.
Any ideas how to prevent menu shifting?
Using Bootstrap v3.3.1

That is how my menu looks like:

```
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" id="navbar-brand">MySite</a>                
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="home">
                <a href="/" class="btn_main"><i class="fa fa-home" title="home"></i></a>
            </li>               
            <li><a href="/contact">About</a></li>
        </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="/account/login" id="loginLink">Login</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

here is my modal popup:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="form-contact" id="form-contact" class="form-validation">

                <div class="form-group">                        
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email" ng-model="contact.email" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group hide">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="hidden">
            </form>                                
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

            <label for="submit-form" class="btn btn-warning font-bold">Click!</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
I just found a fix here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14040

```
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-top,
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
padding-right: 17px;
}
```

Does that means that it is a bug in bootstrap?

**UPDATE 2**
The above behaviour applied to all latest WebKit based browsers, but just checked IE 12 and there the whole page shifting right when modal appeared.

Comment: May indeed be a bug, try using the newer version of Bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, it's an open bug in Bootstrap.